# Java Spring boot re-saves object in database instead of referencing it

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an object, let's name it `Factory`. The factory Object is mapped with a `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` relationship with an Object named `Car`. So I could do something like:

```
factory1.setCar(car1);
factory2.setCar(car1);
```

However, once I save those factories in the database, I would like them to reference the same car object.

```
factoryRepository.save(factory1);
factoryRepository.save(factory2);
```

Instead, after saving I get 2 saved factories and 2 saved cars (different IDs but same values). Any idea on how to save the car1 Object once and make the 2 factories point to that object, using Java Spring-boot?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the car is new, then save the car first. Alternatively you could save factory1 first and then do `factory2.setCar(factory1.getCar())`

Comment: I don't have access to the `carRepository`, only to the `factoryRepository`. Also, for your second suggestion, I would get an error saying `duplicate key value`.